# Is it possible to stop script after 5 seconds have passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery plugin called "[jQuery illuminate](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-illuminate)"

It's working fine and looks great but one more thing that I want!
I only want it to illuminate for 5 seconds.
Then it should stop illuminating.

But it looks there's no option for that.
Is it possible to stop illuminating after 5 seconds have pased?

My code is this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a#request', function()  {
        $(".box#input").val($(this).attr('value'));

        var input = $(".box#input");
        $(document).scrollTop(input .offset().top - 60);
        input.focus();

        input.illuminate({
        'intensity': '0.3',
        'color': '#e8f7e7',
        'blink': 'true',
        'blinkSpeed': '1000',
        'outerGlow': 'true',
        'outerGlowSize': '20px',
        'outerGlowColor': '#228b22'
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the end of your script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button").illuminateDie();
}, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds
```

That calls the `illuminateDie` function after five seconds. The existence of the `illuminateDie` function is sort of hidden away in a comment part-way down the page you linked. (That's also quite a non-standard way to do it. The standard way for a plug-in to provide methods like that is as a string you feed into the one plug-in method, e.g. `.illuminate("die")` or more normally `.illuminate("destroy")`. But it's what the author decided to do...)

---

**Update**: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/edokut/1) using code from the updated question ([source](http://jsbin.com/edokut/1/edit)).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$('#button').illuminateDie()` should work.
It should be straight forward if look into source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').illuminate({
            'intensity': '0.3',
            'color': '#98cb00',
            'blink': 'true',
            'blinkSpeed': '1200',
            'outerGlow': 'true',
            'outerGlowSize': '30px',
            'outerGlowColor': '#98cb00'
        });
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#button").illuminateDie();
       }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

As you can see in the [comments](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-illuminate/#comment-599) of the plugin. You might have wanted to check those out.

Comment: What's all this `...e();/);` about?

Comment: @Connor My bad. Fixed.